# Emulator process is immediately killed in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Studio in a new laptop, and now I cannot get AVD to work.
When I try to run a device, I get a message `"The emulator process for AVD <AVD-name> was killed"` 
immediately after launching the device.
I have tried with API 29 and 30.
I have installed the following tools
[image]
If I try to run the emulator by command line I get:

```
C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd Nexus_6_API_30
emulator: Android emulator version 30.6.5.0 (build_id 7324830) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
added library vulkan-1.dll
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:315: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
emulator: INFO: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:93: Advertising in: C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_11172.ini
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
VCPU shutdown request
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 25 ms
VCPU shutdown request
```

I think everything is the same as what I had in the other laptop, expect in this one I am using HAXM. But if I unistall HAXM, I cannot launch a device in AVD, and I have to install it again. I don't know if it is related to the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nuno

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by disabling the "HP Sure Click" services and restarting my computer (my new laptop is an HP)